# Click every button with the same class on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, console

I'm trying to play around with a Facebook group chat I made a while ago. The plain fact is I added too many people and I need to remove absolutely everyone. 
This is the html of one of the buttons (they all share the same class):

```
<a class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy" role="button" href="#" ajaxify="/chat/remove_participants/?elem_id=u_32_4&amp;uid=1124361845&amp;tid=958151054268315" rel="async-post">Remove</a>
```

So with that, I hoped to use this here and it'd click all the buttons at once:

```
 document.getElementById('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy').click();
```

But the error message...:

```
VM1719:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null(…)
```

comes up.. I'm really confused as to why the click function doesn't work.

Cheers

Comment: Id != class. To select by class you need `document.getElementsByClassName('theClassName');`

Comment: Don't scrape Facebook. Use the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select DOM Tree Elements by its classname, `getElementById()` is not a correct option, because it selects the element by its ID. So, instead you should be choosing `getElementsByClassName()` which returns an array of elements with that class name. Then you can loop over the elements to click it programmatically.

```
var group_chat_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy');
for (i = 0; i < group_chat_buttons.length; ++i) {
    group_chat_buttons[i].click();
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks tons

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementById()`, which gets an element **by ID**. You should use `getElementsByClassName()`.

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy');
for (let btn of btns) {
    btn.click();
}
```

It matches **all elements** and the `for-of` loop iterates each matched element with the selected class name.

Comment: Oh okay, well I imput that and I got another error:
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function(…

Comment: Got my answer but I'm still curious as to why this didn't work :/

Comment: Updated my answer.